# jQuery: setting focus doesn't work in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, focus

I created a pretty simple form input validation using JavaScript:

- Invalid inputs are marked up with some error text
- If there is any invalid input, the focus is set to the first one

This works very well, except in IE11.

https://codepen.io/accessibility-developer-guide/pen/LjwyoR

Here's the relevant code:

```
$elementToFocus.focus() if $(':focus').length == 0
```

I search on StackOverflow and tried it using timeouts, but this didn't work either. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> This works very well, except in IE11.

The issue is:

```
$(':focus')
```

In IE11 this selector returns the **BODY** element when there is no focused element. If you read in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) it's better to specify a selector. In your case, you can simply exclude the body:

```
$(':not(body):focus')
```